# Getting an error when using jsonRpcService on Xpages

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes, xpages-ssjs, xpages-extlib

I'm trying to use jsonRpcService to print a value on console. Just for testing.
But when i call the method i recieve this error on browser console:

```
POST http://localhost/Teste.nsf/Teste.xsp/RpcService?$$viewid=!ei0pdt23xx! 400 (Bad Request)
Error: Unable to load /Teste.nsf/Teste.xsp/RpcService?$$viewid=!ei0pdt23xx! status:400(…)  
Unable to load /Teste.nsf/Teste.xsp/RpcService?$$viewid=!ei0pdt23xx! status:400  
Error: Unable to load /Teste.nsf/Teste.xsp/RpcService?$$viewid=!ei0pdt23xx! status:400(…)  
Error: Unable to load /Teste.nsf/Teste.xsp/RpcService?$$viewid=!ei0pdt23xx! status:400(…)
```

Here is the image of the error:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/T5ekl.jpg

I already searched a lot for one solution to this error but i got nothing.

This is the code that i'm using:

```
<xe:jsonRpcService id="jsonRpcService1" serviceName="metodos"
    pathInfo="RpcService">
<xe:this.methods>
    <xe:remoteMethod name="teste" script="print('teste')"></xe:remoteMethod>
</xe:this.methods>
</xe:jsonRpcService>
```

And this is the code that i'm using on console to call the function

```
metodos.teste()
```

Does anyone knows what i'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: "metodos" is the name of the jsonRpcService. The browser recognize it and if i use "metodos.teste()" the function will be called, but after this the service returns an error and because of that error i cant handle the return of the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to **return a value** in your script and your client has to wait for answer with a **callback** function.

This is a working example:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view
    xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core"
    xmlns:xe="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/coreex">
    <xe:jsonRpcService
        id="jsonRpcService1"
        serviceName="metodos"
        pathInfo="RpcService">
        <xe:this.methods>
            <xe:remoteMethod
                name="teste"
                script="return 'teste'">
            </xe:remoteMethod>          
        </xe:this.methods>
    </xe:jsonRpcService>

    <xp:button
        value="Test"
        id="button1">
        <xp:eventHandler
            event="onclick"
            submit="false">
            <xp:this.script><![CDATA[
                var deferred = metodos.teste();
                deferred.addCallback(function(result) {
                    alert(result);
                });]]></xp:this.script>
        </xp:eventHandler>
    </xp:button>

</xp:view>
```

When you click on button "Test" an alert box shows up with the message "teste".

You can add additional code before `return 'teste'` like your original `print('teste')`. The script just has to return something...

Comment: Thank you, That was the problem.

Comment: Knut, On my local application this code works, but when i put it on another application that is on a server the code returns me the same error. Do you know any possible cause for this?

Comment: I think this error is caused by some server config. I'll try to solve it. If i succeed i'll post here.

Comment: Doing tests here i realize that if i restart the http server the code works great, but when i login in any database on the server the code stops to work even if i log out.